Exercise on capital budgeting
Consider a project of buying a new machine with several assumptions. The exercise is to compute the NPV and see if the project is worth it.

When doing capital budgeting like this, do we always consider free cashflow instead of "standard" cashflows? It seems to be the case in books (Berk-DeMarzo), but why do we add depreciation back, substract capital expenditure etc ?
What does it mean to have a net working capital investment at the start of year 1 ? If I make a table sumarizing revenues and costs, I believe that we often assume that payments are done at the end of the year (is this a wrong assumption to make ?). So here should the investment be on year 0 (end of year 0) or on year 1 (end of year 1) ? (nothing more is mentioned regarding the timing of revenues and costs).



but why do we add depreciation back, substract capital expenditure etc

I assume you're doing an "indirect" method of calculating cash flow by starting with net income and trying to infer how much of that was cash. A rough estimate can be done by starting with the net income that the project will bring in (positive means a cash inflow), "adding back" depreciation since it is a non-cash expense, and subtracting capital expenditure since it is an outflow does not affect net income (it gets converted to assets and is not an "expense").
For example - if you have a project with a projected net income of $50 and depreciation expense of $10, you can assume that the net cash inflow for the project was $60 ($10 was subtracted from net income as a non-cash depreciation expense). If you also spend $20 on "capital expense" for the project, then the total net cash inflow would be $40 (the $60 net operating cash minus the capital expense)

What does it mean to have a net working capital investment at the start of year 1 ?

It's common to include an outflow at the very start (you can call it "beginning of year 1" or "year 0" or "today") since that's how most projects work - you spend money today but don't see the cash inflow until later. For academic purposes it's common to assume that the flows are all at the end of each period since the math lines up more easily - your first period cashflow is discounted by one period, the second by two periods, etc.
